# Javascript no imprime por pantalla después de un for

Tags: javascript

estoy empezando en JavaScript y no sé si tengo un problema de sintaxis o qué puede ser. El caso es que después de un bucle for, no me imprime por pantalla, sí imprime justo antes, pero no lo que se declara después.
Sólo es un ejercicio de un libro y debería ser sencillo pero no funciona.
El código del ejemplo:

```js
// JavaScript source code
var matriz = new Array(4); // Creamos un array vacío de cuatro posiciones
//En cada posición del array definimos e inicializamos un vector
matriz[0] = new Array("La Diligencia", "John Wayne", "Claire Trevor", 1939);
matriz[1] = new Array("El Hombre que Mató a Liberty Wallace", "James Stewart", "Lee Marvin", 1962);
matriz[2] = new Array("Sin Perdón", "Clint Eastwood", "Morgan Freeman", 1992);

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            document.write(matriz[i][j] + "<br>");
        }
        document.write("-----------------------------------------------------<br>");
    }

var vector1 = new Array("Cary Grant", "Ava Gardner", "Al Pacino");
var vector2 = new Array(1904, 1922, 1940);
var vectorFinal = vector1.concat(vector2);

document.write("Contenido concatenado: " + vectorFinal);
document.write("Contenido de vector final: " + vectorFinal.join() + "<br>");

var vectorOrdendo = vectorFinal.sort();
document.write("Contenido del vector ordenado: "+vectorOrdendo.join()+"<br>");

var vectorReverse = vectorFinal.reverse();
document.write("Contenido del vector ordenador con reverse: "+vectorReverse.join()+"<br>");
```

Comment: Aunque no es incorrecto, casi nadie usa `matriz = new Array(a,b,c...)`. Se suele escribir `let matriz = [a,b,c...]`, más corto e igual de legible. En tu caso podrías incluso hacer algo como `[ [a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i] ]`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Es que el libro que estoy siguiendo es de 2018 y quizá esté un poco desfasado.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que deberías usar [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), ya que tu bucle `for` recorre primero el array 1 y luego el array 2, haciendo que `matriz[i][j]` sea `undefined`

```js
// JavaScript source code
var matriz = new Array(4); // Creamos un array vacío de cuatro posiciones
//En cada posición del array definimos e inicializamos un vector
matriz[0] = new Array("La Diligencia", "John Wayne", "Claire Trevor", 1939);
matriz[1] = new Array("El Hombre que Mató a Liberty Wallace", "James Stewart", "Lee Marvin", 1962);
matriz[2] = new Array("Sin Perdón", "Clint Eastwood", "Morgan Freeman", 1992);

    matriz.forEach(el => {
        el.forEach(w => {
            document.write(w + "<br>");
        });
        document.write("-----------------------------------------------------<br>");
    });

var vector1 = new Array("Cary Grant", "Ava Gardner", "Al Pacino");
var vector2 = new Array(1904, 1922, 1940);
var vectorFinal = vector1.concat(vector2);

document.write("Contenido concatenado: " + vectorFinal);
document.write("Contenido de vector final: " + vectorFinal.join() + "<br>");

var vectorOrdendo = vectorFinal.sort();
document.write("Contenido del vector ordenado: "+vectorOrdendo.join()+"<br>");

var vectorReverse = vectorFinal.reverse();
document.write("Contenido del vector ordenador con reverse: "+vectorReverse.join()+"<br>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenías un pequeño fallo en el bucle externo (el que usa `var i`) al tenerlo como `for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)` existe un momento en el que trata de entrar en `matriz[3]`, que no existe en tu matriz (llega solamente hasta `matriz[2]`.

Modificando el bucle para que solamente itere por él mientras `i` sea menor de 3 te debería de funcionar.

```js
// JavaScript source code
var matriz = new Array(4); // Creamos un array vacío de cuatro posiciones
//En cada posición del array definimos e inicializamos un vector
matriz[0] = new Array("La Diligencia", "John Wayne", "Claire Trevor", 1939);
matriz[1] = new Array("El Hombre que Mató a Liberty Wallace", "James Stewart", "Lee Marvin", 1962);
matriz[2] = new Array("Sin Perdón", "Clint Eastwood", "Morgan Freeman", 1992);

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        document.write(matriz[i][j] + "<br>");
    }
    
    document.write("-----------------------------------------------------<br>");
}

var vector1 = new Array("Cary Grant", "Ava Gardner", "Al Pacino");
var vector2 = new Array(1904, 1922, 1940);
var vectorFinal = vector1.concat(vector2);

document.write("Contenido concatenado: " + vectorFinal);
document.write("Contenido de vector final: " + vectorFinal.join() + "<br>");

var vectorOrdendo = vectorFinal.sort();
document.write("Contenido del vector ordenado: "+vectorOrdendo.join()+"<br>");

var vectorReverse = vectorFinal.reverse();
document.write("Contenido del vector ordenador con reverse: "+vectorReverse.join()+"<br>");
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu aporte. Efectivamente, aquí estaba el error.

Answer (score 1):

El único problema en tú código es que al principio estás creando un array de 4 posiciones... pero solo llenas 3.

Y el ciclo está así:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
```

Entonces al llegar a la posición 4 falla.

Si lo cambias solo hasta la posicion 3 funciona:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya esté resuelto, se le puede dar otra vuelta de hoja, y hacerlo más dinámico, imagina que después quieres añadir más Arryas:

```
var matriz = new Array(3); // Creamos un array vacío de cuatro posiciones
//En cada posición del array definimos e inicializamos un vector
matriz[0] = new Array("La Diligencia", "John Wayne", "Claire Trevor", 1939);
matriz[1] = new Array("El Hombre que Mató a Liberty Wallace", "James Stewart", "Lee Marvin", 1962);
matriz[2] = new Array("Sin Perdón", "Clint Eastwood", "Morgan Freeman", 1992);

console.log(matriz.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
            document.write(matriz[i][j] + "<br>");
        }
        document.write("-----------------------------------------------------<br>");
    }
```

Yo pondría en el new Array(el 3, porque tienes 3 Arrays, si tuvieras más vale, pero con estos cambios solamente tienes que añadir un array más, y sumar +1 a este número).

Luego en el bucle for, pon de valor de cierre del bucle un length de los Arrays, y siempre te dará buen resultado.